# Wordpress crashed during update

Tags: fatal-error

I was updating Wordpress when my wifi dropped - now I'm getting.....

> error: Call to undefined function `wp_raise_memory_limit()` in `/www/sites/46e/fb3/www.mywebsite.co.uk/web/wp-admin/admin.php` on line 141

Any ideas how I can fix this?

Comment: upload via ftp...

Comment: try <strong>MANUALLY</strong> updating. Download a fresh copy of the WordPress .zip file to your computer, unzip it, and use that to copy up all files and folders <strong>EXCEPT the wp-config.php file and the /wp-content/ directory.</strong> You may need to delete the old wp-admin and wp-includes folders and files on your server before uploading the new ones. Please read the <a href="http://codex.wordpress.org/Updating_WordPress#Manual_Update">Manual Update</a> directions first.

Answer (score 2):

Some files were not copied during update. You need to copy again wp-includes/functions.php to define `wp_raise_memory_limit()`, but it's better to upload again all files and folders of wp-includes and wp-admin, as soon as you correct this error, another one will certainly appears, and until all required WordPress files will not be there...